# cómo conseguir que un label de un checkbox no se meta debajo de él si es demasiado grande con respecto al ancho del div que las contiene

Tags: html

No consigo hacer que este ejemplo funcione ajustando la etiqueta a la derecha del checkbox si es que esta es demasiado largo con respecto al div de 100px.

Adjunto el ejemplo.

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <tr valign="bottom">
    <td>
      <div style="float:left; width:100%;">
          <input type="checkbox" id="aceptoImagen" name="aceptoImagen" value="SI">
          <label style="word-wrap:normal; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¿Quiero que se rompa en varias lineas si el texto es my largo  y no se meta debajo del check sino que se quede alineado a su derecha siempre ?</label>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución rápida que no requeriría muchos cambios: añádele el estilo `display:flex` al `div` que contiene el `input` y `label`. Por defecto se alinearán en columnas ajustándose su ancho automáticamente al contenido (entonces como el texto es más largo empujará el `input` a la izquierda, ocupando todo el espacio restante a la derecha).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando con ese mínimo cambio:

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <tr valign="bottom">
    <td>
      <div style="float:left; width:100%; display:flex;">
          <input type="checkbox" id="aceptoImagen" name="aceptoImagen" value="SI">
          <label style="word-wrap:normal; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¿Quiero que se rompa en varias lineas si el texto es my largo  y no se meta debajo del check sino que se quede alineado a su derecha siempre ?</label>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Modifiqué tu HTML porque así como estaba (tr dentro de un div) no tenía sentido. Espero que la respuesta te sirva.

**Primero**, tienes que decirle al label que su **alineación** sea `inline-block`. Esto es, que aparezca junto al checkbox pero en forma de caja y de esa manera no desborde hacia la izquierda en el segundo o tercer renglón.

**Segundo**, tienes que darle un **ancho explícito** al label, calculando más o menos que entre paddings y otros estilos por defecto el checkbox ocupará unos 30px de ancho. Esto es, si tu contenedor tiene 150px de ancho, el label sólo puede tener hasta 120px de ancho antes de generar un break implícito. Si no le das un ancho fijo (y dado que fijaste `inline-block`), el label intentará usar todo el espacio disponible y generará un break implícito.

**Tercero**, le dices que su **alineación vertical** sea `top` para que la primera línea del label calce con el checkbox, y no quede éste en la mitad o la base del texto.

En resumen:

- para que no desborde: `display: inline-block`
- para que el inline block no genere un break: `width: 120px` (tú verás cómo ajustarlo)
- para que el checkbox quede alineado con el primer renglón: `vertical-align: top`.

  ```css
  .contenedor {
  float:left; 
  width:100%;
  }
  .milabel {
  word-wrap:normal; 
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102); 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-style: normal; 
    padding-top: 3px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table style="width:150px">
      <tr valign="bottom">
          <td>
              <div class="contenedor">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="aceptoImagen" name="aceptoImagen" value="SI">
                      <label for="aceptoImagen" class="milabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;¿Quiero que se rompa en varias lineas si el texto es my largo  y no se meta debajo del check sino que se quede alineado a su derecha siempre?</label>
              </div>
          </td>

      </tr>  
    </table>
  ```

Si no sabes el ancho del contenedor, o éste es flexible, siempre puedes decirle al label que su ancho sea `calc(100% - 30px)`, aunque esto a veces requiere ciertos ajustes cuando usas un preprocesador.

(También podrías decir que tanto el checkbox como el label tengan `float:left`. Esto equivaldría a darle `display:inline-block` a ambos elementos, pero no se visualiza exactamente igual y de todos modos necesitas dar un ancho explícito al label.)

**Hay otras maneras de hacer esto mismo** reemplazando el conjunto input+label con otras combinaciones (puede ser un elemento `a`, puedes separarlos usando dos celdas de una tabla, puedes usar un flex-grid) pero la gracia de dejarlo tal como está es que un label puede tener el atributo `for` que lo asocia al checkbox, y permite pinchar indistintamente en el label como en el checkbox, lo cual es positivo para la experiencia de usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que cambies de etiqueta `<label>` a `<p>` ya que `p` se ajusta a toda la línea y ademas puedes utilizar la alineación hacia la derecha para eso...

```html
<div style="width:100px">
  <tr valign="bottom">
    <td>
      <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="aceptoImagen" name="aceptoImagen" style="width: 30px; display: inline-block;" value="SI">
        <p style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 65px; word-wrap:normal; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; padding-top: 3px; cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp;¿Quiero que se rompa en varias lineas si el texto es my largo y no se meta debajo del check sino que se quede alineado a su derecha siempre ?</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Pol, te lo comentaba en otra pregunta, pero te lo pongo también en esta: lee [answer] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](/help/formatting) para ver consejos sobre cómo dar formato a tus publicaciones y que se vean mejor. Además, esta respuesta realmente no soluciona el problema expuesto por la pregunta.